# Styling React Modal with CSS classes creates irremovable border

Tags: css, reactjs, react-modal

An example can demonstrating this behavior can actually be found in React Modal's official example: https://codepen.io/claydiffrient/pen/KNjVrG

If you add a className attribute to your ReactModal, the following will happen:

After Modal opens, mousing down on the overlay (purple background in the example linked) will remove the thick black border and show what you have actually styled in your CSS. I have defined custom portalClassName, overlayClassName, bodyOpenClassName,  htmlOpenClassName, and className (all custom attributes are at: https://reactcommunity.org/react-modal/) for my ReactModal and gave all of them a `border:none !important` and `box-shadow:none !important` and yet this thick black border still persists.

A workaround is using inline custom style, but I like to keep my styles all in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to achieve what I think you're after by declaring a style for the modal:

```
<Modal
isOpen=true
style={modalStyle}
/>
```

and then setting both the overlay and content as `border: none` as per the below:

```
const modalStyle = {
    overlay: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '95px',
        bottom: '70px',
        left: '50%',
        marginLeft: '35px',
        marginRight: 'auto',
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -0%)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)',
        border: 'none',
    },
    content: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '0px',
        left: '0px',
        right: '0px',
        bottom: '0px',
        background: '#fff',
        overflow: 'auto',
        WebkitOverflowScrolling: 'touch',
        padding: '10px',
        border: 'none',
    }
};
```